How do I check whether something from a list exists in a string?
password = "B"
prac = ['A', 'B']
if any(prac) in list(password):
    print("yes")

This is not working as I thought it should.
I assumed it would return “yes” however it doesn’t and just returns nothing. I believe it has something to do with how I’m checking if a character from a list exists in a variable

if password in prac?

Either
if any(p == password for p in prac):
    print("yes")

Or
if password in prac:
    print("yes")

